# Android : How to verify email address using OTP

Tags: java, android, email, email-verification, one-time-password

In my android application registration I am planning to ask users email address, so i can use the same for if they forgot their application password.So I need to verify the given email address and I found that there is no provision to confirm the existence of email address.But I think if we can send a OTP to that email then that help me to verify the email id.How can I do that??If anyone know that please help me.I need to send the OTP to email and ask the users to enter the OTP and then verify the same.

Comment: You need help about ideas or technical?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost you need to have SMTP server through which you will send email.

Rest is simple code to send emails and there are plenty of examples like [this one](http://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-sending-email-using-java-mail-api)

Once you are able to send OTP, then from app you can capture that piece of info and send it back it your server for verification using any networking library like Async tasks volley OlHTTP etc.